# Take data points from my power point graph and put them into an excel sheet

Tags: python, json, excel, powerpoint

Years ago for a masters project my friend took a bunch of data from an excel sheet and used them in a powerpoint graph. He told me he made the graph in excel then copied it into powerpoint. Now, when I hover over the graph I see the points associated to where my mouse hovers. My friend lost the original excel sheet and is asking me to help pull the data from the powerpoint graph and put it in an excel sheet.

How would I go about doing this? If theres away to get the points into a json file I can do the rest. I just know nothing about powerpoint graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the chart, choose Edit Data.
If it's an embedded chart, the chart and its workbook will open in Excel.
From there you can File | Save As and save your new Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

years ago I used a program called DataThief - takes a scan of a graph and produces x's and y's according to how many you ask for for resolution.
Amazingly it is still around DataThief III and you can find it here:
http://datathief.org

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this has to do with Python.  Also, I'll bet anything the data is already coming from Excel and it's converted into a PowerPoint slide.  I doubt it's working the way you described it.  Check out the Macro below and see if it helps you with your project.

```
Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()

Dim objPPT As Object, _
    PPTPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation, _
    pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Set PPTPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open("C:\PPT_Deck.pptx")
Set pSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(5)

If pSlide.Shapes.Count <> 0 Then
    'Table
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Named Range").Copy
    pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    'OR
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Named Range").CopyPicture
    pSlide.Shapes.Paste

    'Charts
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph1").ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    'OR
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph1").ActiveChart.ChartArea.CopyPicture
    pSlide.Shapes.Paste
Else
    MsgBox "There is no shape in this Slide (" & pSlide.SlideIndex & ")." & vbCrLf & "Please use a slide with at least one shape, not a blank slide", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a useful macro for pasting pictures (not data) from Excel INTO PowerPoint; OP is looking to extract data from a graph in PowerPoint because the original Excel file isn't available. I don't think this will help in this case.